# Cleaning S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

We have a Ruby on Rails back-end application that stores/uploads (via CarrierWave) some images to Amazon S3. My problem is in our bucket there are old images that are not in database anymore. My problem is I cannot come up with any cleaver idea to clean up those old images from bucket.

First thing that comes my mind is

- get all the links from rails database
- get all links from bucket
- find which ones are not used
- delete them

Is there any better approach to achieve this?